# Azure Data Factory How to Join Comma Delimited String Column to String Column

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

Working with ADF (I am not well-versed in ADF) and maybe I am approaching this wrong. This is all in the context of working in a dataflow. The scenario is, I have a table (table A) that has a comma delimited list of strings and another table (table B) with a string column that could have a matching value to table A in it.

I see two ways to get to the end here but I cannot seem to figure out how to Google my way out of this.

One way could be to join the two tables together using an IN clause in the join statement. Something like:

```
select b.*
from TableB b
join TableA a on b.SingleStringColumn in (a.DelimitedColumn)
```

I cannot figure out how to write a join like this in ADF

The other way this might be done is by having a select activity that pipes in the column for TableB to use in an IN clause. Something like:

```
select b.*
from TableB
where b.SingleStringColumn in (PipedInDelimitedColumn)
```

Is there any way to do either of these in an ADF dataflow that does not require stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Custom (cross) join** to specify the above condition in Data flow.

**This is my sample data of TableA:**

[image]

**Data of TableB:**

[image]

In the Join transformation of Dataflow, select Custom join and give the condition like below.

```
instr(DelimitedColumn, SingleStringColumn)>0
```

[image]

**Result**:

[image]